# How to skip parsing different format row. Fasterxml csv parsing

Tags: java, csv, parsing, fasterxml

I have csv file like this:

```
headerA;headerB;headerC
val1;val2;val3;
val4;val5;val6;
some_word;val7;
```

So. The last line is different. It doesn't fit to `headerA;headerB;headerC` format. `some_word;` is like a subheader for `val7`.

Question is: how to parse csv document properly? How to get this `val7` and other values or skip last line of the file?

I am using fasterxml to parse it.
My code is:

```
CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.builder()
                .setColumnSeparator(';')
                .setStrictHeaders(true)
                .setUseHeader(true)
                .build();
        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        MappingIterator<OuterData> readValues =
                mapper.readerFor(OuterData.class).with(bootstrapSchema).readValues(outerDataContent);
        return readValues.readAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it with an xtext.
Not that difficult, and now i have clean model of my csv file.

1. Download eclise installation
2. Select Eclipse DSL Tools while installation
3. Run eslise DSL
4. Create new project "Xtext Project". Dont forget to tick Facets > Eclipse plug-in
5. Than go to your base name package > src > [your base package]. There you'll see *.xtext file
6. Describe your .csv file
7. Near you'll see *.mwe2 file. Right click on it > Run As > MWE2 Workflow. It will generate everithing you and eclipse need
8. Right click on your base name package > Run As > Eclipse Application > Launch Runtime Eclipse. It will run new instance of an eclipse application, but it will be your instance of an eclipse.
   Here you should create new project with *.[your_extention] file. your_extention is an extention you selected on the first page when you created the project.
9. Put your csv file content to this new file.

now, if you want you can open this file with Sample Reflective Ecore Model Editor (right click on your file > open With > Sample Reflective Ecore Model Editor). There you will see your csv file "parsed" in that way you described before in *.xtext file.

Now, you need to create *.jar file to implement it in your java project. Nothing's special there.

> mvn clean package install

I don't remember, but i am thinking first i build [your base package].parent package and then build [your base package].

==================

In your java project you should do something like this:

```
// init dsl model. It's standalone because it can work without eclipse and stuff
NameOfYourXtextProjectStandaloneSetup.doSetup();
NameOfYourXtextProjectStandaloneSetupGenerated ssg = new NameOfYourXtextProjectStandaloneSetupGenerated();
// get injector to get environment members
Injector injector = ssg.createInjector();

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourCsvTextAsString.getBytes());
XtextResourceSet resourceSet = injector.getInstance(XtextResourceSet.class);

Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("name.[your_extention]"));
try {
    resource.load(inputStream, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error while reading from resource");
    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
return (List<TransactionsFile>) (EList) resource.getContents();
```